# UITextfield limit The Chinese characters length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

```
#define MAXLENGTH 12
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (textField.tag == NICKNMAE_TAG) {
        NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
        NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
        NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

        NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;

        BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

        return newLength <= MAXLENGTH || returnKey;
    }
    return YES;

}
```

I used this methods to limit the length of the textfield. It worked when iputing the usual
characters. Unfortunately, it doesn't work when inputing the Chinese characters.

Comment: can you give some example input and output so people can see the exact problem?

Comment: The textfield has input 10 Chinese characters like "哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈" and then input any characters, will appear some words. You choose anywords, the keyboard will provide associations related to the word choice. Choose the related words, the total length will longer than the maxlength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inputing some languages that uses a input method, the input of your pinyin makes `-textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` get called, and when you select your Chinese characters, another call to this method occurs, sadly, you can't distinguish whether this method is called by inputing pinyin or changing pinyin to Chinese.

So it's always better to allow user input more characters than you limit, but not allowing user to submit the input. You can see how Weibo does this when user input there feed.

**I'v found another solution:**
You can use @property markedTextRange, by which you can get if there is any Pinyin that is waiting for Chinese character selection, if there is any, you don't limit the input string length, and once user turn all Pinyin into Chinese character, you can truncate the Chinese string upon your limit.

Comment: YES, I use the methods like Weibo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
UITextField *textField = [UITextField new];
[textField  addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (void)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSString *text = textField.text;

    UITextRange *selectedRange = [textField markedTextRange];
    UITextPosition *position = [textField positionFromPosition:selectedRange.start offset:0];

    NSInteger maxLegnth = 5;

    if (!position)
    {
        if (text.length > maxLegnth)
        {
            NSRange rangeIndex = [text rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:maxLegnth];
            if (rangeIndex.length == 1)
            {
                textField.text = [text substringToIndex:maxLegnth];
            }else {
                NSRange rangeRange = [text rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:NSMakeRange(0, maxLegnth)];
                textField.text = [text substringWithRange:rangeRange];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**swift version:**

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self
            , action: #selector(XXXXX.textFieldValueDidChanged(_:))
            , forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

func textFieldValueDidChanged(textField: UITextField) {
        let limit = 100
        let txt = textField.text ?? ""

        guard nil == textField.markedTextRange else { return }

        if txt.characters.count > limit {
            let finalTxt = txt.substringWithRange(txt.startIndex..<txt.startIndex.advancedBy(limit))

            textField.text = finalTxt
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same question and my lovely colleague give an solution.

We need add a target as of `UITextField` for `UIControlEventAllEditingEvents`.

`[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(actionTextFiledDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEditingEvents];`

If `textFiled.markedTextRange` is not nil, truncate the text to fit the max length, else leave it.

```
- (void)actionTextFiledDidChange:(UITextField *)textFiled {
    if (textFiled.markedTextRange == nil &&  textFiled.text.length > MAX_NAME_INPUT_LEN) {
        textFiled.text = [textFiled.text substringToIndex:MAX_NAME_INPUT_LEN];
    }
}
```

In the `UITextFieldDelegate`, the logic doesn't change.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSInteger newLen = textField.text.length - range.length + string.length;
    return (newLen <= MAX_NAME_INPUT_LEN);
}
```